# $\sin(iy)=i\sinh(y)$; what is the value of $i\sin(iz)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\sin(iy)=i\sinh(y)$; what is the value of $i\sin(iz)$ ?

NOTE : $z=x+iy$

$\sinh(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$and$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$$

> $$i\sin(iz)=i\dfrac{e^{-z}-e^z}{2i}=-\sinh(z)$$

Or $\sin(iz)=i\sinh(z) \to i\sin(iz)=i^2\sinh(z) \to i\sin(iz)=-\sinh(z) $

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the real and imaginary parts from below:

> $$\large i\sin(iz)=i\sin (-y+ix)=\frac{e^{-x-iy}-e^{x+iy}}{2}=-ie^{-x}\sin y-e^{iy}\sinh x$$